# Reporting users who just creates noise on SE?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't seem to find any similar post here on META regarding my question.

Is there a way to somehow "flag" or otherwise report users who only creates noise on SE?

I have run into a few users which either spammed or asked completely irrelevant questions on SE.
I know we can flag their posts, but has there been put any thought into placing a "report user" button on their profiles, or has it been avoided in fear of it maybe promoting hetz?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just flag one of their posts or comments. If you are noticing a pattern of abuse, you can always choose the "other" option and give us the details.